# express session is not working with vuejs and axios

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, passport.js, axios

Session initialize in express.js also used passport.js for local-authentication which is working fine. But the session/cookie is not working

```
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '../../dist'));

mongoose.connect(config.database, function(err){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log('Connected to DB');
})

app.use(cors({
    origin:['http://localhost:8080'],
    credentials: true // enable set cookie
}));

app.use(logger('dev'));  
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'false' }));

// required for passport
require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.use(session({ 
    secret: config.secret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
 }));
// session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

Get request with axios is below

```
axios.get(this.url + '/user', {withCredentials: true})
     .then(response => {
         console.log(response);
      })
     .catch(e => {
         this.errors.push(e)
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [tutorial to store sessions or cookies using passport.js and express.js](https://www.airpair.com/express/posts/expressjs-and-passportjs-sessions-deep-dive)

```
app.use(session({ 
    secret: config.secret,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: true }
 }));
```

instead of this try:

```
 app.use(express.session({ 
        secret: config.secret,
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: { secure: true }
     }));
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: const session = require('express-session'); it was required like that  .. express.session does not work that you're referred. But the tutorial that you give me I dive into this tutorial and find a solution there a section ->  ExpressJS 4.0 Middleware Order. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.